# A question about QT BLE : Service error: QLowEnergyService::OperationError

Tags: qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I use qt to communicate with BLE devices, I encounter some problems.
Among the BLE devices I want to link, there are four Bluetooth services, and I choose one of them for data transmission. This service always displays "Service error: QLowEnergyService::OperationError".
But other services can't, and they can communicate normally. Only this service will have this problem, and after sending data, the returned data shows that the sent data is incorrect.

I hope someone can help me find out the cause of this problem.

I use the windows platform and compile it into msvc64bit.

Comment: What kind of service is this? Have you tried accessing the service using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?